# How can I disable system_traces keyspace in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

We use Cassandra 2.1.5 in a small dev environment (2 DCs, 3 nodes each).
We don't have much space on dev machines and almost every day face disk space errors. Main culprit is system_traces keyspace :

```
.../system_traces]# du -sh
8.1G    .
```

I tried to turn tracing off in cqlsh:

```
cqlsh> tracing off;
Tracing is not enabled.
```

I tried nodetool settraceprobability 0 - but still tables are getting populated.

I can't delete tables and keyspace:

```
cqlsh> drop keyspace system_traces;
Unauthorized: code=2100 [Unauthorized] message="Cannot DROP <keyspace system_traces>"
```

The only working solution is "truncate system_traces.sessions; truncate system_traces.events;" - but those tables are getting full of rows quite soon.

How do I disable it once and for all?

Comment: You must still have tracing enabled somewhere. Have you checked your client applications? Which language/driver do you use?

Comment: Java, Achilles. Nothing about tracing in the client code.

Comment: Try to look at a few rows, that might give you a hint as to what generates these traces. For instance, when I trace a CQL query manually, the query string appears in `sessions.parameters`.

Comment: @Olivier Michallat you were right. Turned out Achilles enables trace logging for entities which have TRACE logging in slf4j. So if you set your.company.package to TRACE in logging, you automatically get CQL tracing in Achilles. Can you add your answer as, well, an Answer so I can mark it as a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must still have tracing enabled somewhere. Try to look at a few rows, that might give you a hint as to what generates these traces. For instance, when I trace a CQL query manually, the query string appears in `sessions.parameters`.

Answer (score 6):

Theres a chance the trace probability was enabled too, You can disable it via nodetool at runtime:

```
nodetool settraceprobability 0
```

but would have to be done on each node. You can truncate the events/sessions tables

```
cqlsh> truncate system_traces.events;
cqlsh> truncate system_traces.sessions;
```

but may want to then clear snapshots if truncate triggered one.

```
nodetool clearsnapshot system_traces
```

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I have already executed settraceprobability 0, did not help.

Answer (score 1):

nodetool settraceprobability 1 helped me to start tracing and getting data in those system_traces tables like sessions and events. Earlier it was not showing any data for me. I did same step on all nodes.  So that make it clear that nodetool settraceprobability 0 should stop the logging if we do it on all tables.